# Merging software deployment and vm provisioning in Ansible + Ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, devops

Most examples of Ansible usage I've seen seem to try and separate machine provisioning from software deployment.

In that, they will have a dynamic inventory of hosts, add a host to that inventory and than deploy the application on the matching host.

For certain services, it seems more logical (to me) to merge the two steps and include the instance deployment in the playbook that deploys the software.

Is this something that can be done in a practical way with ansible ? How would I go about launching my ec2 instance and (in the same playbook), deploying an application on it, without having to have any entity external to the playbook to which the new host's identifiers are added ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about programming. It's a question for Software Engineering SE or DevOps SE.

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is specifically in AWS, it makes more sense to bake the software on to an AMI and then spin up node from that. Any fine tuning of the VM could be done using cloud-init module or similar.

Generating AMI and spinning up VM are done in two stages, and, Ansible could be used in both to automate.

Comment: A) This is a bit too complex for my usecase, considering that spinning up an instance and getting the ip is a 1 liner with aws ec2.

Comment: B) An AMI is also very solid, if I want to have a bunch of variables when launching my service I'd still have to add an extra configuration step once the VM boots up (and it follows that I would need to add the host inventory to do that).

Comment: But it could be a better solution if I end up having to use ansible for something like this.